# GeoServer SLD Parsing Error on unknown rule

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I tried loading an SLD file generated from QGIS 3.18 into GeoServer and I keep getting the message below.
I suspect the error is from one or more of the rules,
but I don't know how to get the feedback about the malfunctioning rule, the file has close to 200 rules and I want to avoid testing each one by hand.
The rules were generated by saving an SLD from QGIS after converting the rules from a .lyrx file using the QLYRX plugin so I don't have another format that GeoServer can read.

Is there an efficient way I can get a report of none supported symbology rules?

```
2021-05-23 09:54:53,606 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES 2021-05-23 09:54:53,633 
ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] -  java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Graphic: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4b45a2f5)   at 
org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:202)   at 
org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse(SLDHandler.java:157)     at 
org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedSld(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:721)  at 
org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedStyle(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:734)    at 
org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getStyle(ResourcePool.java:2053)     at 
org.geoserver.catalog.impl.StyleInfoImpl.getStyle(StyleInfoImpl.java:110) 
    at
```

### Edit

adding a part of the sld containing `Graphic` as requested.
This is only a part of one rule, the entire SLD is more than 11,000 rows long.

```
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>shape://horline</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#3cc74e</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>15</se:Size>
                  <se:Rotation>
                    <ogc:Literal>45</ogc:Literal>
                  </se:Rotation>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

As requested adding the output of

```
grep WellKnownName mavat.sld | sort -u
<se:WellKnownName>shape://horline</se:WellKnownName>
```

[image]

### Stack Trace From The GeoServer UI

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Graphic: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4b45a2f5)
    at org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleAdminPanel$7.onClick(StyleAdminPanel.java:415)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerAjaxFormLink.onSubmit(GeoServerAjaxFormLink.java:45)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:787)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor317.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.flow.ControlFlowCallback.doFilter(ControlFlowCallback.java:260)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Graphic: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4b45a2f5)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:202)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse(SLDHandler.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedSld(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:721)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedStyle(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:734)
    at org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleAdminPanel$7.onClick(StyleAdminPanel.java:399)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Graphic: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4b45a2f5)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:153)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:227)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:186)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ElementHandlerImpl.endElement(ElementHandlerImpl.java:232)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParserHandler.endElement(ParserHandler.java:778)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:610)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1718)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2883)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:184)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:200)
    ... 137 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @4b45a2f5)
    at org.geotools.sld.bindings.SLDGraphicBinding.parse(SLDGraphicBinding.java:121)
    at org.geotools.se.v1_1.bindings.GraphicBinding.parse(GraphicBinding.java:63)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:144)
... 156 more
```

Comment: can you include a section of the SLD which uses a `Graphic`?

Comment: Just added, your comment reminded me the problem with QGIS writing `<se:WellKnownName>horline</se:WellKnownName>` instead of `<se:WellKnownName>shape://horline</se:WellKnownName>` but fixing that still didn't help.

Comment: The most likely error is that it is using a "wellknown" name that GeoServer doesn't know - could you try to do something like `grep WellKnownName file.sld | sort -u` and add that to the question

Comment: added, though it seems that `horline` is the only one used.

Comment: Can you please share the full stack trace?

Comment: @AndreaAime just added the output from the Web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by going through rules one by one and when failing through the symbolizers that caused the error.
The main problem was symbolizers that had empty rotation tags like this:

##### Doesn't Work

```
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>shape://horline</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#cc3300</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>14</se:Size>
                  <se:Rotation/>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

This doesn't work with only a closed `<se:Rotation/>` or an open and close tag `<se:Rotation></se:Rotation>`.
The only solution was removing all of these empty tags (I only had rotation, but this might apply to other graphic properties as well), and the GeoServer evaluates the SLD without a problem.

##### Works

```
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>shape://horline</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#cc3300</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>14</se:Size>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a general classloading issue rather than a problem with the specific SLD:

`org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader`

It's talking about "modules". My guess is that you're using either a version of Jetty that is too recent, or a version of Java that is also too recent.
Remember GeoServer is compatible with Java 8 and Java 11, but not with the newer, short lived (non LTS) feature releases.

Comment: I'm using openJDK 11.0.6, would downgrading to 8 help in any way?